# use str_replace to find a number in ( )

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to use **str_replace** in a string

```
$txt = str_replace('[0-9]+','777',$txt);
```

but trying to get ***any number*** with `[0-9]+` does not work :(

May I ask how to achieve this kind of "any number" selection, please?

Thank you :)

---

Edit: I have tried preg_replace but I cannot adapt my code :(

```
preg_replace(
"/".$child."\<\/a\> \([0-9]+\)/",
"/".$child."\<\/a\> \(".ccount($child)."\)/",
$txt);
```

for

`Child</a> (4567)` ---> `Child</a> (8798)`

Do you have an idea, please?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$txt = preg_replace(
    '/(' . preg_quote($child, '/') . '<\/a>) \([0-9]+\)/',
    '$1 (' . ccount($child) . ')',
    $txt);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Does $1 mean stg like 'repeat preg_quote'? Thanks a lot

Comment: @bat.t [Numbered `$n` references in the replacement string tell it to include the matched text of the corresponding `(`...`)` capturing group in the pattern.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: this explains the ( ) around the preg_quote & Co :) Thanks a lot for the explanations

Answer (score 2):

You should use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$txt = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/','777', $txt);
```